# Automatically mount location in GNOME Files (Nautilus) on drag and drop

Tags: gnome, samba, gnome3, nautilus

GNOME Files ([formerly Nautilus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Files)) provides a list of Locations or Bookmarks on the side of the window, for quick access to files in different locations. In this list, I can include Samba shares, which will automatically mount (after prompting me for credentials) the shares when I select them.

After I've mounted a share, I can drag a file to the item in the Locations list and drop it on top of that item, and GNOME Files will copy that file to the share. However, if I haven't first mounted the share, rather than mount the share automatically, GNOME Files will give me an error along the lines of: `There was an error getting information about the destination.`

How can I configure GNOME Files to automatically mount the share, just like it would if I had selected the Location directly? Though Samba shares have prompted this question, the solution may have a more general application to any mountable Location types.

Comment: A trivial solution is to put the samba shares in fstab, so they are mounted on power-up and are always available.

Comment: @NZD: Yes, but since Nautilus can perform that automatic mount on click, I am asking about similar functionality for drag-and-drop.

Comment: https://www.ubuntugeek.com/mount-isos-easely-in-gnome-nautilus.html

Comment: @Adam: If you believe that is an answer, you should post it as an answer.